How to ensure memory consistency with memcpy in a seq_lock implementation for reader/writer threads?
I am using a seq_lock for coordination between a reader and a writer thread. The reader calls load(), and the writer calls store(). Here's a simplified version of my code:
#include <atomic>
#include <string.h>

std::atomic<std::size_t> seq_;
std::size_t push_seq = 0;
char value_[32];
char load_copy[32];
char store_copy[32];

void load() {
  std::size_t seq0, seq1;
  do {
    seq0 = seq_.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
    memcpy(load_copy, value_, 32);
    seq1 = seq_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
  } while (seq0 != seq1 || seq0 & 1);
}

void store() {
  seq_.store(++push_seq, std::memory_order_relaxed);
  memcpy(value_, store_copy, 32);
  seq_.store(++push_seq, std::memory_order_release);
}

Problem:
In the store() function, it's possible that memcpy can be executed before seq_.store(std::memory_order_release), violating the intended memory ordering.
Similarly, in the load() function, memcpy might be executed before seq_.load(std::memory_order_acquire) completes, causing inconsistent data to be read.
My Attempt:
I am considering using std::atomic_thread_fence with appropriate memory orderings (memory_order_acquire and memory_order_release) to prevent this reordering.
Will adding std::atomic_thread_fence in this case solve the problem, or should I be using a different approach to prevent memcpy from being reordered relative to the seq_ operations? Any guidance on how to ensure proper memory consistency here would be helpful.
Will this work?
void load() {
  std::size_t seq0, seq1;
  do {
    seq0 = seq_.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
    memcpy(load_copy, value_, 32);
    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);
    seq1 = seq_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
  } while (seq0 != seq1 || seq0 & 1);
}

void store() {
  seq_.store(++push_seq, std::memory_order_relaxed);
  std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
  memcpy(value_, store_copy, 32);
  seq_.store(++push_seq, std::memory_order_release);
}

Note that there is only one reader and one writer

Replace the first increment with a compare exchange, if the exchange succeed you do the memcpy, otherwise you are in a race with another writer anyway, and the compiler won't be able to reorder it.

@AhmedAEK This looks like a benign data race UB to me, that shouldn't be an issue in practice. Assuming we figure out the correct fence to add to OP's code.

@AhmedAEK I am asking for single writer. Compare exchange is a very costly operation. I am asking for other alternatives

@RishiJain an alternative would be to inject platform specific assembly to give those guarantees, you cannot write a seq_lock in C++11 , period, no fence does what you want to do.

Even my proposal of a compare exchange would fail on a platform where the CPU can reorder writes, most of them don't, but who knows

@AhmedAEK, I've updated the question. Will the above approach work?

Did you even bother to read my answer to your last question ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/78966004/15649230 the acquire cannot prevent a write from being reordered before it, some compilers would issue instructions that make it seem to work but it is not correct according to the standard.

@AhmedAEK
Your statement is: an acquire only prevents subsequent memory reads from being re-ordered before it.
Here memcpy is load and then store. So acquire should prevent it from moving up and release should prevent it from moving down.

@RishiJain but the store above it can move after the memcpy because it is relaxed, you want to make the store above it a release and the fence an acquire_rel so the compiler cannot reorder it. (the same thread is doing both the acquire and release), even then it can still fail on some platforms, although it will likely work on the platforms you will be using for testing (because CPUs can reorder instructions), ie: it won't work on some ARM versions.

This is where the atomic compare-exchange would help, because the CPU cannot do the memcpy until the compare-exchange is successful, the CPU cannot reorder its way out of it

Strictly speaking, you cannot correctly implement a seqlock under the C++ memory model unless you use std::atomic (or std::atomic_ref) for the protected data as well as the lock.  Any concurrent access to non-atomic data, if not purely read-only, is a data race causing undefined behavior.  The seqlock algorithm needs to assume that the worst that can happen with such access is that you might read incorrect or "torn" data, but C++ doesn't give you that guarantee; you could get demons flying out of your nose instead.  There are no "benign data races", officially.

Unfortunately, using std::atomic means you can't use memcpy; you'd have to manually loop over the data to copy it with atomic loads and stores, and that will probably not compile to efficient code.  Now that said, you may be able to get reliable behavior in practice, especially if you know something about which compiler and target architecture you will be using, so it would help if you could specify that.
